# Quiero saber el tiempo de ejecución de mi Insertion Sort

Tags: c++

Quiero saber el tiempo de ejecución del proceso de ordenamiento al poner varios datos aleatorios y me dieron la opción del omp_get_wtime()

pero cuando compilo con el GNU en un proyecto de codeckblocks aparece esto

> === Build: Release in insertion (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===
>   obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2f)
>   undefined reference to `omp_get_wtime'
>   error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   === Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 5 second(s)) ===|

Encontré que debo usar el openmp compiler pero solo vi que esta en intel (no se mucho de este tema) y no se como podré hacerle, mi meta final es sacar los tiempos de ejecución para graficarlos y sacar el valor del algoritmo polinomial (an^2+a(n-1)....+a0) algo asi creo que era la fórmula.

```
include <iostream>
include <omp.h>
include <stdio.h>
include<stdlib.h>
include<time.h>
define ndatos 1000

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int vector[ndatos]= {0};
    int key=0;
    int i =0, j =0;

    for(int c = 0; c < (ndatos); c++)
    {
        vector[c] = rand() % (ndatos);
        cout <<vector[c]<< "  ";
    }

    double x = omp_get_wtime();
    cout << x << "tardo"<< endl;


    for (j=1; j<ndatos; j++)
    {
      key= vector[j];
      i= j-1;
      while(i>-1 && vector[i]>key)
      {
          vector[i+1]= vector[i];
          i=i-1;
      }
      vector[i+1]=key;
    }

    cout<< "\nOrdenados:\n";

    for(j=0; j<ndatos ; j++)
    {
        cout<<vector[j]<<"  ";
    }

    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función que comentas solo estará disponible si habilitas `openmp` en tu aplicación.

Para ello, tal y como se indica en la [documentación](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/Enabling-OpenMP.html) de GCC, tienes que compilar con el flag `-fopenmp`

Adicionalmente, debes incluir la cabecera

```
#include <omp.h>
```

En tu archivo para que el compilador tenga acceso a la declaración de la función.

Comment: !!!1Muchas gracias